# How to Download Image as JPG Compress it and Display it in a ImageView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I download an image from a URL, compress it, and display it in an image view.

The way I am doing it now I am using a Bitmap and the file sizes are large so with over 20 images it slows download and crashed it all together. Is there anyway to do this?

Here is what i have tried

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
        {
            byte [] data = webClient.DownloadData("https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10555140_10201501435212873_1318258071_n.jpg?oh=97ebc03895b7acee9aebbde7d6b002bf&oe=53C9ABB0&__gda__=1405685729_110e04e71d9");

            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data)) 
            {
                var yourImage = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.FromStream(mem) ; 



              //as Jpeg
                yourImage.Save("path_of_your_file.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg) ; 
            }
        }
```

But the `FromStream` , and the `Save` does not work

Comment: What's with the capitalization? Please make an effort when writing your questions!

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: @LachlanGoodhew-Cook added a bit more detail

Answer (score 1):

To download a file (assuming it is already a jpg) and save it just do

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
{
  byte [] data = webClient.DownloadData(image_url);

  File.WriteAllBytes(path_to_file, data);
}
```